# Use specific user in SSPI connection String in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, iis, clickonce

I am making a windows form application(desktop application) that connects to database. I also created a service account domain\user. Now, i deploy my application using clickonce and use IIS to launch my application. In IIS, I set my application pool identity to the service account I created so that my application will connect to database using that service account since that was the only account with access to my database. When I test my application, it failed to connect to my database. It says that user has no connection to database. Upon checking the error, it shows that it used the account of the currently logon user in the pc where my application is launch instead of the account I set in IIS. By the way, I am using SSPI connection string, and my SQL is set to windows authentication. Is it possible for my application to use the account set in IIS to connect to my database? If no, is there a way for me to use the service account I created to connect to my database? Please help,

Comment: What do you mean launch IIS to launch your application, when you said that it is a desktop application.

Comment: please see image i posted below

Answer (score 0):

[image]

here, when i click browse in IIS manager, this will load and when I click lauch, my windows form will load.